# How to string split, match, and output a specific pattern?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to solve a problem which I have done it with PHP, not sure how to do that in Python.

In the following three Rows, we like to match based on these two patterns:

- only vine.co and twitter.com URLs (other domains should be ignored)
- only URLs before commas <kbd>,</kbd> (last URL in each Row should be ignored)

#### Input

```
Row 1: https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a,https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a
Row 2: https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1
Row 3: https://www.gofundme.com/lolas-life-saving-surgery-funds,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1
```

---

The output would be an array in Python (which this output is based on PHP):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a
"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1
"
  [2]=>
  string(63) "https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1"
}
```

#### PHP Code:

```
$input = 'Row 1: https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a,https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a
Row 2: https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1
Row 3: https://www.gofundme.com/lolas-life-saving-surgery-funds,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1';

$array = preg_split('/Row\s\d:\s/s', $input);

$output = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 1) {
        $URL_arrays = explode(',', $value);
        foreach ($URL_arrays as $key => $value) {
            if ($key = sizeof($URL_arrays) - 1) {
                unset($URL_arrays[sizeof($URL_arrays) - 1]);
            } else {
                $match = preg_match('/twitter\.com|vine\.co/s', $value);
                if ($match) {
                    array_push($output, $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

This question is based on [this RegEx problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886865/i-need-to-extract-only-specific-urls-before-comma-if-case-of-multiple-urls-in-a), which you may answer either of which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all URLs having `vine.com` or `twitter.com` domain which have a comma just after the URL,

```
https:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:vine\.co|twitter\.com)[^,\s]*(?=,)
```

As you wanted, the key point is this positive look ahead `(?=,)` which ensures, your URL is followed by a comma immediately after the URL.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/APqrBI/1)**

Python code extracting URLs using `re.findall`

```
import re

s = '''Row 1: https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a,https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a
Row 2: https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1
Row 3: https://www.gofundme.com/lolas-life-saving-surgery-funds,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1'''

print(re.findall(r'https:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:vine\.co|twitter\.com)[^,\s]*(?=,)', s))
```

Outputs,

```
['https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a', 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1', 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't need to hold duplicates, I would suggest to use a set instead of array (but order changes):

```
{url for x in s.split('\n') for url in x.split(': ')[1].split(',')  if 'vine.co' in url or 'twitter.co' in url}
```

**Code**:

```
s = '''Row 1: https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a,https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a
Row 2: https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1
Row 3: https://www.gofundme.com/lolas-life-saving-surgery-funds,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1'''

print({url for x in s.split('\n') for url in x.split(': ')[1].split(',')  if 'vine.co' in url or 'twitter.co' in url})

# {'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/835264098648616962/photo/1', 
#  'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/836677758902222849/photo/1',
#  'https://vine.co/v/5W2Dg3XPX7a'}
```